# asp.net: how to update listbox content on response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

and sorry for bothering with what seems to me as a rather stupid question.

One aspx-page post back to itself. Form-data is collected from request.Form[] and updates a record in a DB. (It's an assignment and we're not allowed to use data bound controls).

Update works well, but when finalizing postrequest with response.redirect("page.aspx") the listbox showing the records shows the *OLD* record. The "listbox" is a regular html-table and filled at page_load-event. When reloading page in browser the updated record is shown.

The assignment restriction of not allowing data bound controls seems like a contradiction to what asp.net is all about, but here I am...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code for populating listbox might be hiding behind ***Page.IsPostBack*** in Page_Load. If that;s the case, then post back of page, would not re-populate the listbox itself.

You will have to invoke the re-poulation method in button click after database update is complete.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No postback-code present. However, the db-class din't close the dbConn upon sql-update. Working ok now.